# The use of global:: for conflicting namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces

From what I understand, the `global::` qualifier allows you to access a namespace that has been hidden by another with the same name. The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx) uses `System` as an example. If you create your own namespace `System`, you can reach the original with `global::System`. The first thing that came to mind is, why would anyone call their namespace `System`?? The page goes on to say this is obviously not recommended, but namespace duplication is very possible in large projects. If/when this does occur, is it a sign that things are heading in the wrong direction, or are there valid reasons to have conflicting namespaces?

Comment: Are there good code smells? :p

Comment: @rpflo: Perhaps he means "is this a severe code smell?"

Comment: Great tag: `evil-doers`.

Comment: If you don't have at least some code smells, you're not on a deadline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One legitimate reason for having conflicting namespaces might be the use of in-house libraries that were written for earlier versions of .Net that didn't contain functionality that was added in later versions.  In the .Net 1.1 days, for example, I wrote a Registry class that wrapped API registry calls.  By pure chance, the method names that I chose were exactly the same as those in the later .Net Registry class, and they did exactly the same things, so it was easy to unplug my homegrown code.  For more complicated stuff, being able to use an older, poorly-named chunk of code with the `global::` qualifier could be useful.

Intentionally naming a new piece of code using an existing .Net namespace would definitely be a code smell, however.

Answer (score 14):

In general, `global::` is used to indicate "I want to start at the top of the namespace structure". If I have a namespace called `MyProduct.System`, then anything that resides in the `MyProduct` namespace will not be able to access the Microsoft `System` namespace. Is it a code smell? Maybe sometimes, but not *particularly* smelly.

Answer (score 6):

Any machine generated code should try and use `global::` in order to minimize potential for namespace conflicts it may not be aware about. Moreover, any of your code which may run into conflicts can use it to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has some good namespace guidelines in the excellent book [`Framework Design Guidelines 2nd Ed.`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613). In general they recommend against introducing comflicts (for instance, by naming your type Stream).

I don't believe I've ever used the global:: qualifier. I would generally consider it a code smell (although there are exceptions, as MusiGenesis and sixlettervariables point out).

Answer (score 0):

I think it just happens from time to time that one of your namespaces has the name of another. For example, I have a namespace .Persistence.NHibernate, where NHibernate could also be the root namespace of the NHibernate assembly.

I don't see any code smell here, it's just naming isses ;)